How to solve this Scrapy HTTP 400 Error that occurs when I try to implement web-scraping using scrapy
Basically, I'm trying to do some scraping with scrapy (still a beginner). However, I don't know what I'm doing wrong because I keep on getting a Crawled 400 bad request error. Specifically: DEBUG: Crawled (400) <POST https://jobs.ashbyhq.com/api/non-user-graphql?op=ApiJobBoardWithTeams> (referer: https://jobs.ashbyhq.com/quora).
2024-04-13 22:38:21 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 https://jobs.ashbyhq.com/api/non-user-graphql?op=ApiJobBoardWithTeams>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
I tried looking at other stackoverflow posts but none of them helped.
class GreenhouseSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'greenhouse'
    allowed_domains = ['jobs.ashbyhq.com']
    start_urls = ['https://jobs.ashbyhq.com/api/non-user-graphql?op=ApiJobBoardWithTeams']
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36'


    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            headers = {
                'Accept': '*/*',
                'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br, zstd',
                'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
                'Apollographql-Client-Name': 'frontend_non_user',
                'Apollographql-Client-Version': '0.1.0',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Content-Length': '787',
                'Cookie': '_dd_s=rum=1&id=06c05356-744b-493d-b0e1-0acd8af3818c&created=1713050309192&expire=1713051227232',
                'Origin': 'https://jobs.ashbyhq.com',
                'Referer': 'https://jobs.ashbyhq.com/quora',
                'Sec-Ch-Ua': '"Google Chrome";v="123", "Not:A-Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="123"',
                'Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile': '?0',
                'Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform': '"Windows"',
                'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
                'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
                'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
                'Traceparent': '00-0000000000000000637909e68290e363-6158ecaf3752b1aa-01',
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
                'X-Datadog-Origin': 'rum',
                'X-Datadog-Parent-Id': '7014616656921145770',
                'X-Datadog-Sampling-Priority': '1',
                'X-Datadog-Trace-Id': '7167771167574516579'
            }
            payload = {
                "operationName": "ApiJobBoardWithTeams",
                "variables": {
                    "organizationHostedJobsPageName": "quora"
                },
                "query": "query ApiJobBoardWithTeams($organizationHostedJobsPageName: String!) {\n  jobBoard: jobBoardWithTeams(\n    organizationHostedJobsPageName: $organizationHostedJobsPageName\n  ) {\n    teams {\n      id\n      name\n      parentTeamId\n      __typename\n    }\n    jobPostings {\n      id\n      title\n      teamId\n      locationId\n      locationName\n      employmentType\n      secondaryLocations {\n        ...JobPostingSecondaryLocationParts\n        __typename\n      }\n      compensationTierSummary\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n\nfragment JobPostingSecondaryLocationParts on JobPostingSecondaryLocation {\n  locationId\n  locationName\n  __typename\n}"
            }
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, method='POST', headers=headers, body=json.dumps(payload), callback=self.parse)```


I tried looking at other stackoverflow posts but none of them helped. 


Well 400 is Bad Request, so your request must be wrong. Check the payload for possible errors. It may be the fact that you're trying to call a graphql endpoint, which isn't really web scraping. Have you tried just making the API call with a regular graphql request (without scrapy)?

Oh wait. Thanks. I just looked into making the API call with a regular graphql right now and I did receive a response with the data I want. Don't think it's the payload or headers though since I used it when making my api call and it worked. Might instead just making an api call if there's no difference in response.

The first thing I would do is removing explicit Content-Length.

As wRAR suggested, you can remove explicit content-length header and try. It is working as expected.
import scrapy
import json

class GreenhouseSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'greenhouse'
    allowed_domains = ['jobs.ashbyhq.com']
    start_urls = ['https://jobs.ashbyhq.com/api/non-user-graphql?op=ApiJobBoardWithTeams']
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36'


    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            headers = {
                'Accept': '*/*',
                'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br, zstd',
                'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
                'Apollographql-Client-Name': 'frontend_non_user',
                'Apollographql-Client-Version': '0.1.0',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Cookie': '_dd_s=rum=1&id=06c05356-744b-493d-b0e1-0acd8af3818c&created=1713050309192&expire=1713051227232',
                'Origin': 'https://jobs.ashbyhq.com',
                'Referer': 'https://jobs.ashbyhq.com/quora',
                'Sec-Ch-Ua': '"Google Chrome";v="123", "Not:A-Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="123"',
                'Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile': '?0',
                'Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform': '"Windows"',
                'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
                'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
                'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
                'Traceparent': '00-0000000000000000637909e68290e363-6158ecaf3752b1aa-01',
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
                'X-Datadog-Origin': 'rum',
                'X-Datadog-Parent-Id': '7014616656921145770',
                'X-Datadog-Sampling-Priority': '1',
                'X-Datadog-Trace-Id': '7167771167574516579'
            }
            payload = {
                "operationName": "ApiJobBoardWithTeams",
                "variables": {
                    "organizationHostedJobsPageName": "quora"
                },
                "query": "query ApiJobBoardWithTeams($organizationHostedJobsPageName: String!) {\n  jobBoard: jobBoardWithTeams(\n    organizationHostedJobsPageName: $organizationHostedJobsPageName\n  ) {\n    teams {\n      id\n      name\n      parentTeamId\n      __typename\n    }\n    jobPostings {\n      id\n      title\n      teamId\n      locationId\n      locationName\n      employmentType\n      secondaryLocations {\n        ...JobPostingSecondaryLocationParts\n        __typename\n      }\n      compensationTierSummary\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n\nfragment JobPostingSecondaryLocationParts on JobPostingSecondaryLocation {\n  locationId\n  locationName\n  __typename\n}"
            }
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, method='POST', headers=headers, body=json.dumps(payload), callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        data = response.json()
        jobs_list = data['data']['jobBoard']['jobPostings']
        jobs = []
        for job in jobs_list:
            title = job['title']
            jobs.append(title)

        print(jobs)

Output:
['Android Engineer - Poe (Remote)', 'iOS Engineer - Poe (Remote)', 'Lead Technical Product Designer - Design Systems, Poe (Remote)', 'Machine Learning Engineer - NLP (R
emote)', 'Product Quality Specialist (Remote)', 'Senior Client Partner - Bengaluru (Remote)', 'Senior Data Scientist - Poe (Remote)', 'Senior Technical Recruiter (Contr
act - Remote)', 'Software Engineer - Ads (Remote)', 'Software Engineer - Full Stack, Poe Core Product (Remote)', 'Software Engineer - Full Stack, Quora (Remote)', 'Soft
ware Engineer - Machine Learning Platform (Remote)']

